# Can a reference in a VBA application to an COM interop assembly be made if there is no Entry in the Registry for the Interop assembly?

Tags: excel, vba, visual-studio, com, com-interop

I wonder if someone could straighten out my understanding on how a reference in a VBA (Excel) application is made to a signed interop assembly (.tlb) produced in Visual Studio 2019 using C#. My confusion has arisen in the course of moving an interop library from one directory to another. The transfer to the new directory was done successfully (eventually) but subsequent experimentation to gain a better understanding has me confused. I was under the impression that such a reference could not be made unless the interop library had been registered. The following is what I did after successfully executing the transfer of the library to its new directory.

1. Deleted the lib reference in the VBA program
2. Deleted all copies of the library from the computer (after copying to a USB Memory stick).
3. Removed the Registry Entry made when VS generated the library. (Via a Registry cleanup program) and confirmed that the registry no longer held an entry to the libraryname.tlb file.
4. Reopened the VBA program and confirmed that there was no entry in the References panel to the library.
5. Copied the library from the USB stick to the desired directory
6. Set reference to the library  in the VBA program. (The Browse function in the References Panel let me do this.)
7. Executed the VBA program that used the library successfully.
8. Searched the Registry for an libraryname.tlb entry. This search did not find any such entry.

How is this possible without the library being registered?

Comment: It is not possible, you'll have to conclude that you did not clean-up the registry correctly.  The .tlb file does not get used when you run the program, only when you compile the VBA code.  It is the .dll that gets used at runtime, it is found through the CLSID registry key.

Comment: It does indeed appear as though my registry cleanup did not do such a good job. A search for libraryname.dll reveals quite a few entries. Can I safely manually delete all the CLSID entries  that refer to this .dll ?

Comment: Thanks for your help Hans. My issues are now totally resolved.